# Why install geth beside Mist and why geth use so much CPU?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, cpu

I have installed new Mist 0.8.3, frist thing after fresh new instalation of ubuntu 16.4.1. I have run *Mist-0.8.3.deb* file and clicked install.

1. How come geth uses so much CPU?

I have i7-6500 processor and geth it is using about 60-70% of CPU just by running Mist, while I'm doing nothing. Just to be clear, all blocks are downloaded.

2. How come, when I type geth in terminal, it says *geth: command not found*?

On page https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases it says *Ethereum Wallet and Mist Beta 0.8.3 + Geth 1.4.12*. Even better, as I asked in first question, geth is using a lot of my CPU so I have to be able to call geth (I supose). In my previous question someone answered me that I can check geth version by command

> sudo apt-cache policy geth

Probobly that would work before I reinstalled ubuntu because I installed specifically go-ethereum 1.5.0, not just Mist like now. I wouldn't do that if there was no bug at version 1.4.11. So it's clear that I have geth 1.4.12, but how can I check that in terminal?

3. While I'm asking this, can someone explain why would I install go-ethereum now when I installed Mist? Even better, if I ever have need to upgrade/downgrade geth, while just having only Mist, what is the best way to do that?

Thank you for answers in advance and regards,

Tomo

Comment: Check `/opt/Mist/nodes/geth/linux-x64/geth` for the geth node after installing the Mist `.deb`; it was a rushed release and somehow moved the geth binary to opt.